# Flutter Firebase merge two collections data in one single array and display data in widget

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'd like to join two collection data in one single array and diplay the result in listView.builder

users(UID, name, email, phone, longitude, latitude),

and trips(userId, date, time, price, from, to).

**PS: the relation between theses two collection is the user ID,**

So I'd like to display for each element a Card with the following details:

Name, Email, Phone, Date, Time, From,To.

How to achieve that?

```
    import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class VoyagerModel {
  var firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  String de, vers, adress;
  DateTime dateTime;
  double price;
  User user;
  String time;
  createVoyage() async {
    await firestore.collection('voyages').add({
      'userId': this.user.uid,
      'de': this.de,
      'vers': this.vers,
      'date': this.dateTime,
      'time': this.time,
      'adress': this.adress,
      'prix': this.price
    });
  }
}
```

and the user model

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class ClientModel {
  String ref = 'clients';

  createUser(
      {id,
      int number,
      String name,
      String email,
      double long,
      double lat}) async {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(id).set({
      'userId': id,
      'name': name,
      'email': email,
      'phone': number,
      'longitude': long,
      'latitude': lat
    }).catchError((err) => {print(err.toString())});
  }
}
```

Comment: The `User` in your VoyagerModel is same at the `ClientModel`?

Comment: yes the same, and the relation between them is many to many

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you are looking for?

```dart
List<VoyagerModel> voyagers = [];
List<User> users = [];

@override
void initState() {
  // Fill voyagers and users
  super.initState();
}

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: users.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          final user = users[index];
          final userVoyagers =
              voyagers
               .where((voyager) => voyager.user.id == user.id)
               .toList();

          return Column(
            children: userVoyagers.map((userVoyager) {
              return Card(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                    Text(user.name),
                    Text(user.email),
                    Text('${user.number}'),
                    Text(userVoyager.dateTime.toString()),
                    Text(userVoyager.de),
                    Text(userVoyager.vers),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            }).toList(),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Name, Email, Phone from users collection; date from and to from voyages collection

Comment: The `VoyagerModel` has a user that contains a name, email and phone. I access on the user assigned to the voyager in each iteration

Comment: No they are different collections, and they are independent the relation between them is just the userid, and they are many to many

Comment: Ok. I suppose you have two different `List`. One is a `List<VoyagerModel` and the other is a `List<User>`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231184/discussion-between-braken-mohamed-and-ignacior).